# Can I collect data from a Flow every two seconds in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I use Code A to colloet data from the Flow `timeXFlow`.

I hope to collect the data every two seconds, how can I do ?

**Code A**

```
val _timeX = MutableStateFlow(0)

viewModelScope.launch {
   timeXFlow.collect {
      _timeX.value = it         
   }
}

val timeXFlow: Flow<Int> = flow {
    var i = 0
    while (true) {
        emit(i)
        i = toDosome( )  // I can't estimate the time
        delay(1000)  
    }
}


@Composable
fun UI(){
   //I hope that xTime can be updated per 2 sec, so UI can repaint with new data.
   val xTime by _timeX.collectAsState()  
   
   ...
}
```

**Added Content**

To Arpit Shukla: Thanks!

The Code B is based your thinking, but your way will lost many emitting datas.

**Code B**

```
val _timeX = MutableStateFlow(0)

private var aa=0

viewModelScope.launch {
   coroutineScope {
       launch {
          while (true) {
            _timeX.value = aa
            delay(2000)   
          }
       }
          
       launch {
           timeXFlow.collect {
             aa = it         
           }
       }
   }
}


//The same with Code A
```

Comment: Why do you want to collect data every 2 seconds? Is the producer producing values too quickly (which doesn't seem to be the case though)?

Comment: I need to update the UI of Line Chart based X axis per 2 sec.

Comment: Ok, I have posted an answer below. I think it's not hard to understand, but if you have any questions, feel free to comment below. I will add more explanation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that comes to my mind is:

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
   var i = 0
   launch {
       while(true) {
           updateUI(i)
           delay(2000)
       } 
   }
   timeXFlow.collect {
      i = it
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks！ Would you please see my updated content in the question?   The  UI  is updated based `MutableStateFlow` automatically in Compose.

Comment: simply replace `updateUI(i)` with `_timeX.value = i`. Won't that work?

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: So you are saying some data might be lost. Do you want to get all the records that have been emitted in past 2 seconds? You can use a list and instead of `i = it`, do `list.add(it)`. And use this list for updating UI